# Querying an entity with property that is converted from List<datetime> to comma separated string. Exception: LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I am using C# application with Entity Framework version 7.0.4.

I have a building entity that one of its properties should be List, I use value converter to save this as comma separated string as the following:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BuildingEntity> builder)
{
    builder
        .Building(x => x.DateGroup)
        .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<List<DateTime>, string>(
                v => string.Join(',', v.Select(i => i.ToString())), // Convert to string for persistence
                v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.None).Select(i => DateTime.Parse(i)).ToList())); // Convert to List<String> for use
}
```

So as to make the entity looks like this:

```cs
public class BuildingEntity
{
  // some props
  public List<DateTime>? DateGroup{ get; set; } = new ();
}
```

The issue is that when I try to make a query on that entity with filter on that column, I receive the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'p => p.Date' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

The query part that causing the issue is:

```cs
query = query
   .Where(r => r.DateGroup != null && 
      r.DateGroup.Select(p => p.Date).Contains(model.DateFilter.Value.Date)
   );
```

DateFilter data type is Datetime?

I was expecting the query to filter the entities by the given date if it exists in one of the dategroup dates property.

Comment: Not the solution for this, but have you considered making that a [json column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns)? That would probably give you more options for such filters?

Comment: `HasConversion` defines compiled methods, which cannot be translated when using in EF query. Consider to use one-to-many relation for this.